# Comparison of ecommerce platforms

Tags: magento, sap-commerce-cloud, atg

I am learning and analyzing the difference between eCommerce platforms like SAP Hybris, Salesforce, WCS, ATG and Magento etc.

What are the key parameters while you zero down to choose a product? And which is the best in the market at present?

Comment: Any list of positive or negative comparisons

Answer (score 2):

This is a broad question that doesn't have a best answer. You could use Gartner to help you decide: https://www.gartner.com/reviews/market/digital-commerce

Personally, I would consider things like:

- **Cost:** Do you want a free platform or a paid one? Some features (or support) may not be available in free platforms. Or, a paid platform may be too expensive for a small company.
- **Existing landscape:** Are you building from scratch without dependencies on other systems, or do you need to consider existing systems (e.g. ERP) in the enterprise? Your customer may already have a SAP system and have a good relationship with them. So, they may want to use SAP Commerce Cloud, rather than Oracle Commerce Cloud
- **Developer experience:** Do developers have experience with an existing platform, or do they need to learn a new platform? What is the learning curve for a new platform like? SAP Commerce Cloud needs Java/Spring background (and maybe Angular for their latest frontend technology).
- **Community / Support:** Is there a community where you can ask questions in case you have a problem? Are there documentation / blogs available?
- **Future of technology:** Is the platform continuously improving or "future-proof", or is it content with staying with old technology? For example, SAP Commerce Cloud's frontend is moving towards Angular, instead of its own technology.
- etc

Answer (score 0):

@geffchang already share some information in his response. I want to add my personnel parameters:

- **Business processes:** Every company has own business processing for preparing products, photos, campaigns, prices, page designs. Some solution has work flow and roles for these changes. If your company small and few people manage it, these work flow steps get extra workload. On the other hand some companies need to approve every changes.
- **Search engine capabilities:** Some products use special search engines such as Solr, Elastic Search, etc. These solutions can manipulate search result, built in synonym and search with root of word support.
- **Other e-commerce related tasks:** Some product has solution for other e-commerce related background tasks. Such as taken product picture, marketing emails/sms, mobile app, wharehouse/stock management, payment integration, cargo integration.
- **Sector/company related functions:** Some solutions has extra functionalities which are not needed for all companies. Such as multi brand capabilities, auto publish new pages/campaigns, ticketing system, region/country/segment based prices, products and pages, business reports (stock, sales, etc.).

At the end, you need to list client needed functionalities and short term future plans then find best fitting e-commerce software for them.